# Python redis: Sort a list containing JSON'd lists by first element in each list

Tags: python, list, sorting, redis

I'm trying to figure out a way to sort a redis list. This list contains lists of [X, Y] values. I'd like to sort on X, ascending.

One of my problems is I could only figure out how to add to the redis list, if the elements were strings first, so I  `json.dumps()` each list before adding it to redis:

```
for i in some_loop:
    redis_json_str = json.dumps(
        [
            unix_time_millis(time), # <--- Need to sort on this, ascending
            str(algorithm_value)
        ]
    )

    # Then I add it to redis (and trim it after to only keep the 50th "freshest" values)

    rds.rpush("alg-" + str(algorithm_parameter.id), redis_json_str)
    rds.ltrim("alg-" + str(algorithm_parameter.id), -50, -1)
```

The values on `redis_json_str[0]` are time values in MS from epoch. They are meant to be used on a time based graph.

When I retrieve the list from redis, I need to be sorted. I'm trying to figure out a way to do this operation within redis first, but if that's impossible, I can try doing it in python after retrieval.

I retrieve the list in another view like this:

```
result_values = rds.lrange("algo-" + str(param_id), 0, -1)
```

I'm using `RPUSH` to put insert items into the list, then `LRANGE` to retrieve it somewhere else in the website.

This is an example of the output when retrieving:

('x' and 'y' are added by me to make reading the example easier, and I also trimmed some of the 'x' values as MS from epoch is a large number)

```
'x': 940880.7622, 'y': '0.5685352436168158'
'x': 935089.762, 'y': '0.5685352436168158'
'x': 935661.762, 'y': '0.5685352436168158'
'x': 938553.762, 'y': '0.21320071635628374'
'x': 937978.762, 'y': '0.9949366763293833'
'x': 940309.762, 'y': '0.9949366763293833'
'x': 939138.762, 'y': '0.9949366763293833'
'x': 939716.762, 'y': '0.21320071635628374'
'x': 936235.762, 'y': '0.5685352436168158'
'x': 955547.3489, 'y': '0.21320071635628374'
'x': 955547.3489, 'y': '0.21320071635628374'
'x': 956696.3489, 'y': '0.21320071635628374'
'x': 955547.3489, 'y': '0.21320071635628374'
'x': 956123.3489, 'y': '0.5685352436168158'
'x': 957268.3489, 'y': '0.9949366763293833'
'x': 957268.3489, 'y': '0.9949366763293833'
'x': 958415.349, 'y': '0.9949366763293833'
'x': 955547.3489, 'y': '0.21320071635628374'
'x': 956696.3489, 'y': '0.21320071635628374'
'x': 957841.3489, 'y': '0.21320071635628374'
'x': 956123.3489, 'y': '0.5685352436168158'
```

As you can see, the 'x' values on the overall list are out of order. The list retrieval should ideally give me back the list of lists in ascending order by the first element of each list.

I'm new to using redis for this (we were using DB calls before but we need this to be faster, so we're skipping disc operations for this one graph that is very time sensitive), and I'm looking at [Redis SORT](https://redis.io/commands/sort), but I'm not sure if this is my use-case here, and I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: What are you using LTRIM for? Is this is a working code? Its very strange that you are doing a RPUSH but the LRANGE is showing you the list out of order. Why is the unix timestamp 10 digit? If its millisecond, it should be 13 digits. Is this working code or pseudo code?

Comment: This is all working code. I trimmed the unix timestamp to make it easier to read here (original values in milliseconds are more like `1613067959642.349`. Using `LTRIM` to discard anything older than 50 elements (like a rolling list, only keeping the newest 50 elements added, because, as far as I understand redis, it will keep adding to a list and not discarding elements unless it's told to, right?

Using RPUSH to add newer elements to the TAIL of the list, in theory that should've been enough to sort my list, as newer unix timestamps should've been added at the end